# Postgresql 9.3 ignores pgpass.conf file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Using Windows 10 and PostgreSQL 9.3.

I have a batch file that executes a series of pg_dump commands to back up selected tables in a database, and a related file that uses psql to restore them into an empty database.  For every call to pg_dump or psql, I have to enter a password.  On customer's machines (usually some version of Windows Server), I have a pgpass.conf file to specify the password, and I don't have to enter it every time.

My pgpass.conf file contains `localhost:5432:*:someuser:somepassword`.  I have tried putting it in `%APPDATA%/postresql` and putting it into a folder named `c:\misc` and creating an environment variable named PGPASSFILE containing `c:\misc\pgpass.conf`.  I restarted the PostgreSQL service after I changed each one.

What am I missing?

Comment: File permissions? I don't use MS-Windows but under Linux (IIRC) a users .pgpass file needs to be set as non-readable by anyone other than the user (`chmod 600`)

Comment: @gsiems I don't think this applies to Windows.

Comment: I'd use a tool like ProcMon to see where it looks for the file, that will give you a clue what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is sort of a non-answer.

I figured I should try with a supported version of PostgreSQL, so I installed 9.6.  I assigned it port 5435.  I added a corresponding line to the file pointed to by my PGPASSFILE environment variable.  It worked.  I tried targeting my 9.3 database.  It still worked.  I removed the line for port 5435.  It still worked.  I copied the pgpass.conf file into the default %appdata%/postgresql folder, deleted the PGPASSFILE and it still worked!

So, I have no idea what was broken, nor do I have any idea what fixed it, but it's fixed.